# Saving a file in Preview.app so it keeps annotations "live"

Tags: preview, image-editing

When I edit an (e.g.) PNG file in Preview.app, I can make text annotations, draw arrows, etc.   I find this very useful, like a quick and free mini-Photoshop.

Of course, when I save the file back to PNG, all the annotations are "baked in" to the image and I cannot edit them, delete them, etc.

Is there a format in which I can save my image file which keeps the annotations "live"?

Comment: Have you tried saving as a pdf, before doing your annotations.

Comment: What about [Freefrom](https://support.apple.com/guide/freeform/welcome/mac)?

Comment: I am struggling to see how this has anything to do with Apple.  Its the PNG format or the OP is asking for a software recommendation.

Comment: @RohitGupta It's about solving a practical problem on a Mac, which is perfectly on-topic.